# Calling specific values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one set up for a branching text adventure, but I was wondering how to organize and call specific values with a function.

Here's what I have:

```
choices = {
1: {'prompt': {
    'prompt': 'Do you want a dog?',
    'A': 'Yes',
    'B': 'No',
    'C': 'Maybe'},
    }
}


def print_situation(prompt):
    print(prompt)
    print(A)
    print(B)
    print(C)
```

Ideally, I want to be able to call `print_situation(1)` and have it print out the following:

```
Do you want a dog?
Yes
No
Maybe
```

Knowing this, what is the correct way to call the values in the `print_situation` function? I'm a little stuck on the correct way to do this given how I have my dictionary set up so any help would be great.

Comment: does the order of output matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_situation(prompt):
  print(choices[prompt]['prompt']['prompt'])
  print(choices[prompt]['prompt']['A'])
  print(choices[prompt]['prompt']['B'])
  print(choices[prompt]['prompt']['C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
choices = {
1: {'prompt': {
    'prompt': 'Do you want a dog?',
    'A': 'Yes',
    'B': 'No',
    'C': 'Maybe'},
    }
}

def print_situation(sel):
    print(choices[sel]['prompt'])
    print(choices[sel]['prompt']['A'])
    print(choices[sel]['prompt']['B'])
    print(choices[sel]['prompt']['C'])

print_situation(1)

# OUTPUT
# Do you want a dog?
# Yes
# No
# Maybe
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The dictionary name is `choices` not `prompt`

Comment: @galfisher, sorry about that. Fixed.